# I can't set an empty array in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I'm setting up an app and in this app have a list, the items in this list have a title and a button to remove the item, I can remove almost all item but when rest one element I cant remove, but I can... I just cant setState an empty array. I'm using lodash to remove the elements.

I've tried to put the new array in the aux var and check if the size is equal to zero and setState an empty array directly instead of the remove function do this.

```
class FuelReservesFilterView extends React.Component {
  state = { plates: [] };

  goToOperationsSearch = () => {
    Actions.selectOperationView({
      backSceneKey: "fuelReservesFilterView",
    });
  };

  goToPlateSearch = () => {
    Actions.selectPlateView({
      backSceneKey: "fuelReservesFilterView",
    });
  };

  goToStatusSearch = () => {
    Actions.selectStatusVehicleView({
      backSceneKey: "fuelReservesFilterView",
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.placa) {
      if (_.last(this.state.plates) != this.props.placa) {
        this.setState({
          plates: [...this.state.plates, this.props.placa],
        });
      }
    }
  }

  renderBtnOperacao() {
    if (!this.props.operacao)
      return (
        <ButtonRounded
          onPress={this.goToOperationsSearch}
          textColor={ACCENT_COLOR}
          label={i18n.t("Select_operation")}
        />
      );
    else
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToOperationsSearch}>
          <View>
            <TextTitle style={styles.textStyle}>
              {this.props.operacao.nome}
            </TextTitle>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
  }

  renderBtnStatus() {
    if (!this.props.status)
      return (
        <ButtonRounded
          onPress={this.goToStatusSearch}
          textColor={ACCENT_COLOR}
          label={i18n.t("Select_status_vehicle")}
        />
      );
    else
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToStatusSearch}>
          <View>
            <TextTitle style={styles.textStyle}>
              {this.props.status.nome}
            </TextTitle>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
  }

  renderPlateItem({ item }) {
    return (
      <ClearItem
        withIcon
        onPressIcon={() => {
          this.removerItem(item);
        }}
        id={item.id}
        text={item.placa}
        icon="close"
      />
    );
  }

  removerItem = item => {  
      this.setState({ plates: _.remove(this.state.plates, function(plate) {
          return plate.placa != item.placa;
       })
    });
  };

  renderPlatesList() {
    if (_.size(this.state.plates) > 0) {
      return (
        <FlatList
          style={this.props.style}
          data={this.state.plates}
          renderItem={this.renderPlateItem.bind(this)}
          keyExtractor={plate => plate.placa}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <ButtonRounded
          onPress={this.goToPlateSearch}
          textColor={ACCENT_COLOR}
          label={i18n.t("Select_plate")}
        />
        {this.renderPlatesList()}
        <Divider space={20} />
        {this.renderBtnOperacao()}
        <Divider space={20} />
        {this.renderBtnStatus()}
        <Divider space={20} />
        <TextTitle>{i18n.t("Minimal_level")}</TextTitle>
        <CustomSlider
          min={0}
          max={100}
          metric="%"
          onValueChange={value => console.log(value)}
        />
        <TextTitle>{i18n.t("Maximum_level")}</TextTitle>
        <CustomSlider
          min={0}
          max={100}
          value={100}
          metric="%"
          onValueChange={value => console.log(value)}
        />
        <Divider space={20} />
        <ButtonRounded
          style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}
          textColor={PRIMARY_COLOR}
          label={i18n.t("Apply_filter")}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: PADDING_VIEW,
  },
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {},
)(FuelReservesFilterView);
```

Comment: I can't understand what you say. Can you be a bit more clear please?

Comment: I have an array with 3 elements, setup in flatlist,etc. To setup the data to flatlist I use the 'state', so when I remove the elements one by one, the last a I can't remove

Comment: Any error you see in console ?

Comment: I think you are passing the ```this.state.plates``` its a const type 
according to lodash docs https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#remove 
try passing a local copy of plates array to remove function and than check the size and set the state.

Comment: I did not understand, can you give me an example?

Comment: like : let array = this.state.plates;

Comment: no error in console

Comment: Is the `removerItem` always being called? If it is can you check that the size of `teste` is correct for each call to the removerItem function.

Comment: just when click the button, I update de code removing the var aux teste, because the lodash returns an empty array to me and doesn't need of the teste aux

Comment: can you create a functional example?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using lodash? It can be done with functions built-in arrays. Remove lodash function is mutating the state variable that is something unacceptable in React.

```
state = {
    items: [
      { name: "John", id: 1 },
      { name: "Paul", id: 2 },
      { name: "jonathan", id: 3 }
    ]
  };

  removeItem = id =>
    this.setState(prev => ({
      items: prev.items.filter(item => id !== item.id)
    }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <div onClick={() => this.removeItem(item.id)} key={item.id}>
            remove {item.name} id {item.id}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think this is not the problem, even when I called setState ({plates: []}), the same thing happened the last element

Comment: I think you should make some changes with my advice. Probably your `componentDidUpdate` is a problem. I don't have sandbox but if I think properly `this.props.placa` is an element from an array. When the component is updated and the array in the state is empty (comparison `undefined` with an element) the condition is always true and you update new state with that one element. If the element from props is the same as in component state I'm right

Comment: I think you're right, make sense. Now I have another problem -_-'

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: I've to clear the props to make the if clause be false, so I use the Action.refresh({placa: undefined}) and solved my problem :), thank you